# Stepmania noteskin: How to detect chart type?

Tags: mods, stepmania

I have a Pump noteskin, and I want the receptors to show differently in `pump-halfdouble` than the other chart types. Specifically, I want to have a graphic for the usual set of 5 receptors as the center tile, but instead show a set of 3 receptors on the RightUp and LeftUp tiles in Half Double charts.